# Common Lisp function that shortens a list

Tags: list, recursion, linked-list, common-lisp

I am a super CL beginner and I am very stumped on the following task:

> Define a recursive function **`shorten`** that deletes the last *n* elements from a given list. The function should return the shortened list at the end.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
>  (shorten 5 '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9))
>  =>
>  (1 2 3 4)
> ```

Comment: someone else needed `trim-to` which seems to do what you want, see: [Trimming a list using Lisp programming language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58071550/trimming-a-list-using-lisp-programming-language)

Comment: If you can write a function `all-but-last` that returns a list with the final element removed, then you can write `shorten` by calling `all-but-last` recursively, reducing `n` by one on each recursive call.

Comment: If you don't know this resource I hope it helps: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/data-structures.html

Comment: Try implementing the "reverse" function first, which reverses a list.

Answer (score 1):

My plan to do this would be, having `p0` pointing at the list's start, go along the list `n` times and get `p2`; then use `p1` initially equal to `p0` and go along the list each time incrementing both `p1` and `p2` until `p2` points at the list's end; then `(rplacd p1 nil)`; and finally return `p0`.

Adjust the above for the corner cases and off-by-one errors.

The repeated incrementing of the list's "pointers" by `(setf p2 (cdr p2))` etc. can be coded with a recursive function instead, by calling it with `(cdr p2)` as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer based on Will Ness's nice trick.  You probably can't submit this as homework.  `tconc` comes from Interlisp, at least its name does.

```
(defun empty-tconc ()
  ;; make an empty accumulator for TCONC
  (cons nil nil))

(defun tconc (v into)
  ;; destructively add V to the end of the accumulator INTO, return
  ;; INTO
  (if (null (car into))
      (setf (car into) (list v)
            (cdr into) (car into))
    (setf (cdr (cdr into)) (list v)
          (cdr into) (cdr (cdr into))))
  into)

(defun tconc-value (into)
  ;; Retrieve the value of an accumulator
  (car into))

(defun shorten (l n)
  ;; shorten list L by N elements at the end
  (check-type n (integer 0))
  (shorten-loop l l n (empty-tconc)))

(defun shorten-loop (l1 l2 n into)
  (if (zerop n)
      (if (endp l2)
          (tconc-value into)
        (shorten-loop (rest l1) (rest l2) n
                      (tconc (first l1) into)))
    ;; Note (rest '()) is '() in CL, hence this abuse
    (shorten-loop l1 (rest l2) (1- n) into)))
```

Answer (score -2):

The solution to this problem is a tail-call recursion. That is to say, when we do each step, we call the function, reducing the count and the input list, and updating a result. When we're done, we return the result. We know that we're done because the counter is zero or the input list is exhausted.

```
(defun shorten (n lst &optional (res '()))
  (if (or (= n 0) (null lst))
      (reverse res)
      (shorten (1- n) (cdr lst) (cons (car lst) res))))

(shorten 5 '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))    ; (1 2 3 4 5)
(shorten 1 '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))    ; (1)
(shorten 11 '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))   ; (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
(shorten 0 '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))    ; NIL
(shorten 5 '())                        ; NIL
```

Comment: Sorry but that's not what the function should be doing (shorten 1 ...) should be equivalent to (reverse (rest (reverse ...)))

Comment: @coredump, sadly I am not a mind reader. The required output is '(1 2 3 4 5), and it delivers that. There's a reason why I find it severely aggravating to post on Stack Overflow, and there's another example.

Comment: FWIW I am not the one who downvoted you and I agree that the test case was badly chosen in the question. I hope you understand I am trying to give helpful feedback here.

Comment: not my dv either, but really, the Q says "Define a recursive function `shorten` that deletes the last `n` elements from a given list". perhaps you missed that part and focused on the example, which I now regret not seeing being possibly misleading and not fixing when I edited the Q.